# Android Opening New Views

Tags: java, android

I have an object holding `JSON`

in my `adapter class` I create a view with the the image stream of movie posters from `TMDB`.

I have a bunch more information I would like the user to be able to access once they click on a poster and are taken to the next view.

My problem is I am having trouble understanding what to put the onlick listener on.

I tried to add a toast to different object in the page, I added a toast to the id of the img in the xml file. But cant get anything to open when I click the image.

This is my adapter class

```
public class adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movie> {

    String url = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185";
    private Context context;
    private List<Movie> movieList;
    public adapter(Context context, int resource, List<Movie> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.movieList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_file,parent,false);
        Movie movie = movieList.get(position);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        tv.setText(movie.getTitle());
        ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(url+movie.getPoster_path()).into(img);
        return view;
    }
}
```

This is my main,

```
  List<Movie> movieList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final RestAdapter restadapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint("http://api.themoviedb.org").build();
        api movieapi = restadapter.create(api.class);

        movieapi.getData(new Callback<MoviesResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void success(MoviesResponse moviesresponse, Response response) {
                movieList = moviesresponse.getResults();

                adapter adapt = new adapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item_file, movieList);
                setListAdapter(adapt);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });
    }
```

So from my understanding I need to set an `onClickListener` on the correct element,
open a new intent and bind the class holding all the information to it?

current view showing the movies posters and titles.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:textColor="#ff010101" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your layout.xml file here?

Comment: I assume you must have a ListView to display the List of all the Movies (posters and titles) right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `ListView` to display the list of movies, then bind the adapter to the ListView and call the `setItemOnClickListener` on the `ListView`. Something of the following sort:

```
ListView moviesDataListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_LISTVIEW_ID);
adapter adapt = new adapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.item_file, movieList);
moviesDataListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

If you are extending `ListActivity` then override `onListItemClick()` listener method to listen to on click of the item in the List.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Item clicked" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // perform required action
}
```

This operation provides the selected ListView and the position of the clicked list item.

For more understanding see this [article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

---

**One Suggestion:**

In your getView() method, try changing the getView() from

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_file,parent,false);
```

to

```
if(convertView != null){
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_file,parent,false);
}
```

So `convertView` is used to reuse old view and enhance the performance.

Hope it helps.